# How to create table definition dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to create a MySql create table statement in java. However the challenge i am facing is that my table's column name are stored in the String Array entered by the user. It is straight forward to run if i know the column names but this time i am trying to create a table on the fly based on the data i receive in my String array

How do i add it dynamically to the create table statement ? any help/tips ?

The create table below is a static one.

```
    static String[] StopNamesForDB;

    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(StopNames);
    StopNamesForDB = new String[set.size()];

        for (String string : set) {


            StopNamesForDB[i] = string;
            i++;
        }


    String sql = "CREATE TABLE Route3 "+
              "(id INTEGER not NULL, " + 
              " first VARCHAR(255), " +
              " last VARCHAR(255), " + 
              " age INTEGER, " +
              " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";
     stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: you create a table and you can alter them later when you know the columns.

Comment: You say that the column names are contained in a String array.  What about the column data types?  Are they all the same (i.e. varchar())?  In your static example, you include a primary key and requisite NOT NULL constraint.  In the dynamic table you want to create, are all columns nullable?  Is there a primary key?  Is the primary key user-definable (or is it a simple int)?  The answers to these questions will determine how to create the code to dynamically create the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
     StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

     sql.append("create table route3(");

     for(String name : StopNamesForDB)
     {
         sql.append(name).append(",");
     }

     sql.append("PRIMARY KEY (").append(StopNamesForDB[0]).append(")");

     sql.append(")");

     stmt.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
```